# Create complex array from list

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have an array with many items similar to this:

```
[
    ["Core", "Mathematics", "Mathematics 20-4"],
    ["Core", "Mathematics", "Mathematics 30-1"],
    ["Other", "Fine Arts", "Art", "some art course"],
    ["Other", "Fine Arts", "Music", "some music course"],
    ["Other", "Forensics", "some forensics course"],
    ["French Immersion", "Core", "Mathématiques", "Mathématiques 30-1"]
]
```

Where the structure is essentially "Department -> Subject -> Course".

I want to dynamically create an Array (or Object) similar to the following (or whatever makes the most sense)...

```
{
    subjects: [
        {
            title: "Mathematics", courses: [ "Mathematics 20-4", "Mathematics 30-1" ]
        },
        {
            title: "Mathématiques", lang: "fr", courses: [ "Mathématiques 30-1" ]
        }
    ],
    other: {
        subjects: [
            {
                title: "Forensics", courses: [ "some forensics course" ]
            },
            {
                title: "Fine Arts", subjects: [
                    {
                        title: "Art", courses: [ "some art course" ]
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Music", courses: [ "some music course" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The "Other" department doesn't necessarily follow "Subject -> Course" and rather can have "Subject -> Subject -> Course" and "Subject -> Course". Maybe adding a type="course" and type="subject" might help, but I'd still like it to have a heirarchy.

I've been banging my head over how to dynamically convert this into an Array or Object structure.

Comment: That Other category is giving me a headache thinking about it.

Comment: It sounds more like you want someone to write your code for you rather than having a specific question or problem.
You could try creating a hierarchy of objects, create objects like: Courses, CourseType, Department, Subject and Course, then pass your array entry into an addCourse function on the base object and parse it to decide whether to add items to an existing object in the hierarchy or create new ones if the Department, Subject or Course doesn't exist. You will still end up with the tree hierarchy you want there but you will be able to break the problem down into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var courses = {};
for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
   var department = arr[i][0];
   var subject = arr[i][1];
   var course = arr[i][2];
   courses[department]= courses[department] || {};
   courses[department][subject] =  courses[department][subject] || [];
   courses[department][subject].push(course);
}
```

That will generate an object in the form

```
courses = {
   core:{
     mathematics:["math1","math2"],
     english: ["english1,"english2"]
   }
  Other:{
    "Fine Arts":[...],
    "Forensics":[...]
  }

}
```

Which I think is what you want.

Then if you want an array of courses for a specific subject for example, you can access it with

```
var courselist = courses[<department>][<subject];
```

Comment: Note that I'm assuming that the last line of data in your question is a typo and you'll always have 3 items in an entry

Answer (score 0):

Using inspiration from @ben336, @user1787152 and also [DevShed forum thread](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=147400&postcount=2) I came up with the following code:

```
var Department,
    departments = [];

Department = function(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subjects = [];
};

function parseTitles( titles )
{
    var i, department, departmentTitle,
        hasDepartment = false;

    departmentTitle = titles.shift();

    for (i=0; i<departments.length; i++) {
        if (departments[i].title === departmentTitle) {
            hasDepartment = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!hasDepartment) {
        department = new Department(departmentTitle);
        departments.push(department);
    }

    departments[i].subjects = titles;
}
```

The subjects are being used as a form of navigation, with the courses being queried via JSON. I'm keeping the subjects as an Array, where when the last child in the subject Array is clicked it will query the JSON for the courses for the subject.

I'll see if I can give credit to @ben336 as he posted the only answer and I'd like to give some credit.